# Input box appears if dropdown "Other" is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my final code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#company").change(function() {
        var val = jQuery(this).val();
        if(val == 'other') {
            jQuery('input[name="other"]').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name="other"]').fadeOut('slow')();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#dropdown").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == 'other') {
            $('input[name="other"]').show();
        } else {
            $('input[name="other"]').hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Updated. as box9 suggested, since you want the function to trigger on page load.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, I really appreciate it. I have used your code and it is showing both the input and the select box, on page load, even when Other is not selected. I have posted my code in the main post again.

Comment: @Kyle - Just trigger it to run on page load by adding `.change()` before the semicolon on the second-last line.

Comment: @kyle-r add a `style="display:none"` to the other input

Comment: @kyle-r Not yet, you forgot to add the final `.change()` see my updated answer.